# In-use connections equal max-pool-size and expired max-wait-time. Cannot allocate more connections

Tags: java, database-connection

I am facing following problem with an `HTTP 500` status.

Message description:

> The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from
>   fulfilling this request.

Exception:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: Error in
>   allocating a connection. Cause: In-use connections equal max-pool-size
>   and expired max-wait-time. Cannot allocate more connections.

Root cause:

> java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: In-use
>   connections equal max-pool-size and expired max-wait-time. Cannot
>   allocate more connections.
>
> note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are
>   available in the GlassFish v3 logs. GlassFish v3

Comment: need more information and your question

Answer (score 2):

Seems that you have a connection leak somewhere in your application.

When you borrow a connection from the connection pool and forget to properly close it, it remains marked as unavailable, causing the exception you   are experiencing.

To locate the leak, you should monitor the connection usage through the JMX connector surely exposed by your application server.

Comment: how can we check connection through JMX connector. As i checked my code and properly closed all the connection

I think there is some configuration problem because i use JNDI and connection pool in this

Comment: We need more information here...  How is the connection pool configured? When does the exception happen? Also, a sample of the code managing the connection would be useful.